# Share Image From Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-sharing

I want to share the current item from a ViewPager but I cannot get the current image and share it.

The share button is only on promotion page's action bar, and it will share the current item from the ViewPager.

This is my adapter:

```
class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
int[] mResources = {
        R.drawable.abc1,
        R.drawable.abc2
};
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mResources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingimages_layout, container, false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
}
```

And this is my Fragment Java code:

```
public class PromotionFragment extends Fragment {
Menu menu;
private PopupWindow Pro_popup;

public PromotionFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);//Menu Resource, Menu
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_promotion, container, false);
    CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getActivity());

    ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);

    LinePageIndicator titleIndicator = (LinePageIndicator)view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    titleIndicator.setViewPager(viewpager);


    return view;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    final int width = size.x;
    final int height = size.y;
    RelativeLayout pro_popup = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pro_popup);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View pro_popupview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.promotion_popup, null);
    TextView qr_title = (TextView) pro_popupview.findViewById(R.id.qr_title);
    TextView qr_con = (TextView) pro_popupview.findViewById(R.id.qr_con);
    RelativeLayout popupbg2 = (RelativeLayout) pro_popupview.findViewById(R.id.prepopup);
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.qr_code);
    Button scan_btn = (Button) pro_popupview.findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
    Button dismiss = (Button) pro_popupview.findViewById(R.id.propop_dismiss);
    dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Pro_popup.dismiss();
        }

    });
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.qr_scan:
            qr_title.setText(R.string.propop_title);
            qr_con.setText(R.string.propop_con);
            Pro_popup = new PopupWindow(pro_popupview);
            Pro_popup.setWidth(width - 80);
            Pro_popup.setHeight(height - 400);
            Pro_popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            Pro_popup.setFocusable(true);
            Pro_popup.showAtLocation(pro_popup, Gravity.CENTER, 0, -60);

            return true;
        case R.id.toolbarshare:
            final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
            CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getActivity());
            ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
            viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
            int position = viewpager.getCurrentItem();
            if(position == 0)
            {
                final File photoFile = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), "abc1.png");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            }
            else
            {
                final File photoFile = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), "abc1.png");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            }
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting adapter in viewpager when user clicks on share button

```
CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getActivity());
ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

remove this code.

you just need to get the position of `ViewPager` when user clicks on share button

```
viewpager.getCurrentItem();
```

Make sure to define viewpager variable globally so that you can access it anywhere in fragment.

One more thing

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
```

It should be at the end of your condition before return statement.